# Split a hermitian form in real and imaginary parts

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

Let's assume $V$ is a complex $n$-dimensional vector space and $h: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a hermitian form on $V$. I wan't to split $h$ into its real and imaginary part, i.e.
\begin{align*}
h = s + ia 
\end{align*}
with $s,a: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. My first question is now, are those linear and if so, are they $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$-linear? Is it even possible for them to be $\mathbb{C}$ linear because they are mappings to only $\mathbb{R}$ this should prevent them from being $\mathbb{C}$-linear shouldn't it? Now I can do the same with the $h$ associated matrix $H$:
\begin{align*} H = S +iA \quad \text{with } S,A \in Gl(n,\mathbb{R})\end{align*}
but my problem ist now, that I expect $S,A$ to be $\mathbb{C}$-linear mappings on V and therefore there image isn't restricted to $\mathbb{C}$. So my second question is now, how can I relate $s,a$ with $S,A$ respectively? Also it is clear using $\overline{H} = H^T$ that $A$ is skew symmetric and $S$ is symmetric. How are those properties connected to the properties of $s$ and $h$?

I'm thinking about this because I later want to define the Kähler form of a hermitian metric on a complex manifold and there is a common theorem that there exists an isomorphism between the real 2-forms and the hermitian metric, that is defined using the imaginary part of a hermitian metric in order to get a real 2-form and vice versa.

I expect that at some point I have to stop seeing $V$ as a complex space but should rather focus on its underlying real structure $V_\mathbb{R}$.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

NOTE: I have allready seen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4427610 but sadly this didn't solve my problems and that is why I want to ask this question anyway.

Comment: First of all, when splitting the form into real and imaginary parts shouldn't it stay a map from $V\times V$ rather than becoming a map $V\to \mathbb{R}$? Secondly, try playing around with $\mathrm{Re}(h)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(h)$ and you should quite quickly see that they have many of the properties you ask of them.

Comment: Also, when dealing with bilinear forms on arbitrary vector spaces, conceptually it is best to not think of it in terms of a matrix, since this requires us to already have chosen a basis and force this basis to be orthonormal with respect to some unrelated hermitian form.

Comment: The imaginary part of the metric is the Kähler form, which is of type $(1,1)$. This means it's not complex linear in its second argument, but it's complex anti-linear.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter I corrected this mistake in my post. Of course it should be $a,s:V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb R$. I think I did also figure out some of the properties those two need to have. But I am still wondering about the linearity of those. The are defined on a complex space but map to $\mathbb{R}$ so the can’t be complex linear can they? 
If I take @QuaereVerum‘s answer in to account they should only be $\mathbb{R}$ linear but are they still define on the complex space or are the only defined on it‘s underlying real structure $V_\mathbb{R}$? Thanks for Your help.